# When physically implementing superposition in a Transmon, what is the actual driving amplitude used in the microwave pulses by Qiskit?

Tags: qiskit, superposition, transmon

I had been playing around with Qiskit Pulse, and I managed to run several single qubit circuits, however throughout these processes, I recurringly came across the driving amplitude and the signal amplitudes in relation to the transmon. Now, I (briefly) understand Josephson junctions and what the oscillation of Cooper pairs means, but how does this relate to an amplitude measured in arbitrary units? More importantly, what is the actual value of this driving amplitude that from the Qiskit backend I can only control from 0 to 1?

If there are some obvious resources in regards to all this that I missed, I'd appreciate the pointer, but I'd also appreciate any help possible!